# Error in running CTRL+C Powershell script in Powershell.exe

Tags: powershell

I want to run a Powershell code in Powershell.exe.

When I type in

```
Copy-Item c:\test\my_file.txt C:\Test\testPSHELL
```

it works fine.

When I copy it and then paste it, I get

```
^V
```

which is normal. But after excecuting I get error:

```
The term '▬' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script   file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was      included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
```

Dont you know where can be the problem? I am getting upset :D

Comment: Paste using right-click into the Powershell console window. Don't ask me why though!

Comment: whaat! thats great, thx!

Comment: @AndyLamb Because that's how pasting into console windows has worked in Windows for about 20 years?

Comment: Yeah, Glad MS improved it from Windows 10. You can copy/paste using the shortcut keys!!

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, right-clicking in a normal command windows (cmd.exe, Windows 7) opens a context menu containing a paste option. In Powershell, right-click pastes directly, no context menu.

Comment: @AndyLamb Not if you enabled Quick Edit Mode (which is one of the first things I always do on any Windows I have to work with).

Answer (score 0):

The reason you got that error is that Ctrl-C is the interrupt command for PowerShell. If you have a long running command that you want to interrupt before it finishes, pressing Ctrl-C will kill the command (This is the same for Linux shells like bash, zsh, etc.)